# Is $\frac{ 2x^2y(x^2-y^4) }{ ( x^2 + y^4)^2 }$ continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: limits

Is $$f(x,y)=\begin{cases}\dfrac{ x^2y(x^2-y^4) }{ ( x^2 + y^4)^2 } & \text{if }  (x,y)\neq 0 \\ 0  & \text{if } (x,y)=(0,0)\end{cases}$$ continuous at $(0,0)$?

I have tried polar coordinates and counter examples, but I have not succeeded. Some help would be great!

Comment: $$\left|\frac{ x^2y(x^2-y^4) }{ ( x^2 + y^4)^2 }\right|\leqslant|y|\cdot\frac{ x^2(x^2+y^4) }{ ( x^2 + y^4)^2 }\leqslant|y|$$

Comment: Function $f$ should defined at $(0,0)$.

Comment: Did, I don't understand how you arrived at those results

Comment: You should change the title.

Comment: You need to show $$ \left| \frac{x^2y(x^2-y^4)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}  \right| \le \epsilon$$ if $$| \mathbf x | \le \delta$$. Now consider Did's suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to show $$ \left| \frac{x^2y(x^2-y^4)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}  \right| \lt \epsilon$$ if $$| \mathbf x | \lt \delta$$. Now consider Did's suggestion. $|y|\le |y|+|x| \le x^2+y^2 \le \delta^2$. So pick $\epsilon = \delta^2$